# A bit confusion with cheat engine function address and IDA subrutine

Tags: ida, disassembly, cheat-engine

I have found a function with Cheat Engine that I like to show in IDA:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3UE7.png)

[image]

but the function is not present in IDA.

Probably I have a bit confusion becouse I don't have experience with this tool.

Can you help me ?

Thanks !

UPDATE:

I have tryed to add image base 400000:

119EDD + 400000 = 519EDD

But 519EDD not exist to IDA:

[image]

There is somthing wrrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you noted the term `battlezone2.exe +`  before the address? That denotes the (usually random) base address of the executable.

In IDA this base address is a fixed value e.g. `0x400000`. Scroll to the beginning of the IDA View and check the `Imagebase` value (hexadecimal). This value you have to add to every address shown in the Cheat engine.

If debugging a process directly with IDA the database is automatically relocated to the correct address so you don't have to do the math yourself.

Note: If I interpret the screen shots correctly 0x119EDD (0x519EDD) is the target address of the conditional jump command. Jump commands are used inside a sub, hence you don't leave the current sub and won't find this address in the sub list

Comment: Thanks !! I have updated question, probably there is something wrong.

Comment: @user3449922 se my updated answer (last section).

Comment: Thank you again, I have already tryied but the only sub that start with 519 on IDA is 519E0C as showed at my last screenshot that is strange.

Comment: Now I have undestand. In short the game is 32 bit but for some reason must be used in IDA PE64.dll. Now with IDA I see 519E0C and all the other functions. Many thanks again !!

Comment: If you have an address you can use Jump -> Jump to address (keycode `G`) to go to a specific address in an "IDA View". Then you don't have to guess which sub to go to.

Comment: thanks you. For your opinion if the game is 32 bit why IDA try to open with PE64.dll ? I have used detours 32 bit but only with this game seem not work (with the others no problem), I need to try with Detours 64 bit with this game ?